# Как в Android запустить активность, чтобы она стала основной?

Tags: android

Если через startActivity(intent) из первичной активности запустить вторую, то при нажатии кнопки "Назад" телефона мы вернемся на предыдущую активность. Как сделать так, чтобы из второй активности шаг назад приводил не к предыдущей активности, а к закрытию приложения (а к первичной чтобы уже никогда не возвращаться)?

Comment: Если захотите углубится в таски и вложенные в них активити то вот вам статья на девелопере, которая мне лично очень помогла разобратся в теме: [Задачи и стек переходов назад](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: Спасибо, почитаем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Способов сделать это много. Самый простой - после старта новой активити, вызвать `finish();` у старой

```
...
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Либо `finishAffinity()`, если активити в стеке больше одной.

Еще одни вариант, можно стартовать активити с флагами:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

и тогда новая активити также будет единственная в стеке.